# How handle a redirect uri where the scheme has to contain https:// in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

Hi I'm trying to implement SSO in my application and i need to use a redirect Uri that contains https://. I got it working in android just fine however in iOS it seems like it isn't possible because iOS reserves https.

I am aware that universal linking is an option but I cant use that in this situation. Any suggestions?

Implementation similar to below

In the iOS implementation after i have authenticated with my service it attempts to redirect back to the app using https://myAppName but the web Authenticator see this as a website and displays it in the browser window erroring saying that it cant navigate to the url.

Info Plist is as follows

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>SSORedirectMyApp</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>https</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

```
internal class WebAuthenticatorBrowser : IBrowser
{
    public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            WebAuthenticatorResult authResult =
                await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new Uri(options.StartUrl), new Uri(options.EndUrl));
            var authorizeResponse = ToRawIdentityUrl(options.EndUrl, authResult);

            return new BrowserResult
            {
                Response = authorizeResponse
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return new BrowserResult()
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = ex.ToString()
            };
        }
    }

    public string ToRawIdentityUrl(string redirectUrl, WebAuthenticatorResult result)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> parameters = result.Properties.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key}={pair.Value}");
        var values = string.Join("&", parameters);

        return $"{redirectUrl}#{values}";
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post any code. Are you using Xamarin Essentials [Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=ios)?

Comment: Yes im using Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator.

Comment: What service you are using? And what exact error shows when redirecting? I find a [sample repo](https://github.com/davidbritch/xamarin-forms/tree/master/WebAuthenticatorDemo) that you can refer to it.